# PHP DateTime get format in UTC without converting object

Tags: php, datetime, timezone

I have an object that has a property that is a `DateTime` object that has a set timezone depending on the user's timezone. At some point I need to store the object where in my storage layer the property is a UTC datetime string, however I may need to continue using the object after it has been persisted and currently my approach converts the object to another timezone and then sets it back to what it used to be:

```
/* "starts" is the name of the property and this is just a "magic" method my driver
    will call before persisting the object. */

public function __persist_starts() {
    $tz = $this->starts->getTimezone();
    $this->starts->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone("UTC"));
    $value = $this->starts->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    $this->starts->setTimezone($tz);
    return $value;
}
```

This appears to be a "hacky" solution, isn't there something clearer I can use. I'm imagining something like

```
public function __persist_starts() {
    return $this->starts->formatUTC('Y-m-d H:i:s');
}
```

Comment: You can always write your own class extending DateTime that includes a new method with that `formatUTC()` code, in the same way Carbon extends DateTime and provides a series of built-in methods for different formats

Comment: @MarkBaker yeah but I'm surprised the guys at php didn't provide this functionality, there must be a good reason for that?

Comment: A good reason? They didn't think it needed to be explicitly provided when it can easily be done in userland code, perhaps?

Answer (score 2):

Although there is nothing like `formatUTC`, there are few other options, slightly better than the *"hacky" solution*:

- if you have such luxury, use `DateTimeImmutable` instead of `DateTime`.
- clone the original object:

  ```
  public function __persist_starts() {
      $utc = clone $this->starts;
      return $utc->setTimezone(new \DateTimeZone("UTC"))
                 ->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
  }
  ```
- create a new object:

  ```
  public function __persist_starts() {
      return \DateTime::createFromFormat(
          'U', 
          $this->starts->getTimestamp(), 
          new \DateTimeZone("UTC")
      )->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
  }
  ```